# Simple way to convert time text strings to ints for numeric operation in Qliksense data load editor

Tags: string, timestamp, integer, qliksense

`TimeTemp` displays as such `168@06:43:23AM`

`stationTime` displays opening and closing times of service area stations as such `6AM-10AM`

I’ve separated `TimeTemp` into 2 different columns, `initialTemp` and `initialTempTime`

I’ve separated `stationTime` into 2 different columns, `openingTime` and `closingTime`

The desired conditional statement is "if not within every 2 hour interval, turn `initialTemp` cell red", so the logic is as follows:

`if(initialTempTime <= openingTime + 2, green(), red())`

which should turn `initialTemp` as green if the expression `<=` is true, else red. However, this has been turning the `initialTemp` cells all into red.

This made me suspect that the expression is not being evaluated correctly and just defaulting to the `else` . I’m confident this is the case as `initialTempTime` , `openingTime` have been confirmed to be of text string data types.

Since a `string + int` cannot be evaluated to a truthy, it defaults to `red()` thus turning all the `initialTemp` cells into red.

The solution would be to typecast the strings into int, so that `openingTime` of say `6AM` can get added 2 hours and the numeric operation can be properly evaluated.

What is a simple way to convert time text strings to ints for conditional numeric operations?

Attempts thus far:

`Time#(SubField(stationTime,'-',1),'hh:mm:ss') as openingTimeTest`
which seems to turn all `openingTime` fields as `-` (null)

`Num(Sum(SubField(stationTime,'-',1) + tempRecordingInterval)) as openingTimeRecordingInterval` where `SET tempRecordingInterval=2;`

`Keepchar([initialTempTime],'0123456789.') as [initialTempTimeNum]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the script below. (ive split it in multiple steps/loads just for clarity)

```
RawData:
Load 
  // convert to time
  Time(Time#( openingTime, 'h:mm:ss')) as openingTime,
  Time(Time#( closingTime, 'h:mm:ss')) as closingTime
;
Load
  // "convert" to time looking string 
  // 6AM will be 6:00:00
  // 6PM will be 18:00:00
  if( index(openingTime, 'AM') > 0, KeepChar(openingTime, '01234567890'),
      KeepChar(openingTime, '01234567890') + 12) & ':00:00' as openingTime,
      
  if( index(closingTime, 'AM') > 0, KeepChar(closingTime, '01234567890'),
      KeepChar(closingTime, '01234567890') + 12) & ':00:00' as closingTime
;
Load
  // split the station time
  SubField(stationTime, '-', 1) as openingTime,
  SubField(stationTime, '-', 2) as closingTime
;
Load * Inline [
stationTime
6AM-10AM
6PM-10PM
];
```

The result table will look like:

[image: Data viewer]

(the display is based on the value of `SET TimeFormat` variable in the beginning of your script)

Once the data is in `Time` format then we can add/subtract hours like this:

`= time( openingTime + 2 / 24 ) // add two hours to openingTime field`

`= time( openingTime - 2 / 24 ) // subtract two hours to openingTime field`

And if we select "06:00:00" value in `openingTime` the two hours addition will give us:

[image: Selection]

Comment: I'll have to look at this more closely tomorrow as it is late over here, but this is essentially what I needed. Thank you!